# Tomcat6 moving libraries onto external disk array

Tags: jar, tomcat6, nfs, catalina

The `catalina.properties` entry for Tomcat6 is as follows:

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,/raid/java/lib/*.jar,/raid/java/lib/spring/spring-security-3.1.0.RE
LEASE/dist/*.jar,/raid/java/lib/spring/spring-framework-3.1.0.RELEASE/dist/*.jar,/raid/java/lib/hibernate/*.jar,/raid/java/lib/jstl/*.jar
```

`server.loader=`

```
shared.loader=
```

where /raid/.. is a disk array mount point attached to another server. Now, am wondering if i can move the ${catalina.base}/lib and ${catalina.home}/lib libs over to /raid/java/..somewhere as well?